# iPad mirror IPHONE app via VGA lead

Tags: iphone, ipad

We have created an iPhone app which our client wants to show on a projector. They want to do this via an iPad (although the app is designed ONLY for iPhone). The app runs fine on the iPad, but it obviously isn't mirrored via the VGA cable.

So the question is, is there an easy way to mirror the output to the iPad screen on the projector? I know I can add the projector as another UIScreen, but my question is really whether there is any easy way to just mirror everything that's happening?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this out of the box on an iPad 2. It directly supports display mirroring by duplicating the video buffer. Unfortunately if you are going to go about this the old fashion way you are going to have to create a new UIScreen and whatever you draw on the mainScreen you need to draw to the external screen too. This gets especially difficult when you involve user interactivity.

I recommend demoing this using an iPhone 4s or an iPad 2. You'll save a lot of time and headaches.